# Find direction between transform in world and mouse pointer using screen space

Tags: unity

I overlay my entire game with a render texture, meaning I cannot use world position for input since the mouse clicks the render texture.

Instead I need to use screen space, I want to find direction between player and mouse so I can rotate player to face the mouse, but I'm not sure how.

[image]

How I did it using world space:

```
    Vector3 mouse = Input.mousePosition;
    Vector3 mouseWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mouse);
    mouseWorld.y = transform.position.y;

    attackDirection = mouseWorld - transform.position;

    // Rotate the character to face the attacking direction
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(attackDirection, Vector3.up);
    transform.rotation = targetRotation;
```

Comment: How does the behaviour of this code differ from what you want? How should answers seek to modify it?

Comment: @DMGregory I cannot use world position for input since the mouse clicks the render texture. I need a solution that uses screen space and can apply the direction found in screen space to the transform of the player in world space.

Comment: The player is always at the center of the screen, so basically direction between center of screen and mouse pointer, then take that direction and apply it to my player who is in world space.